# How to Order a query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, yii, yii1.x

I have an array `$sorted_array` its value is

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 [2] => 6 )
```

Now based on the $sorted_array i created an array

```
$first_array = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('*')
            ->from('form_fields')                                      
             ->where(array('not in', 'id', $sorted_array))
             ->andWhere('form_id=:form_id', array(':form_id'=>$form_id))
             ->queryAll();
```

`$sorted_array` value is the id (Primary key) of table `form_fields`.

When i run this query i get the array `$first_array` but not in the order in which i want it. ie, I will get an array in order $id=1,3,6.

Now my wanted order is 3,1,6 (exactly as `$sorted_array`). How can i get `$first_array` in that order?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11269-order-by-field-in-cdbcriteria/

Comment: @Sougata thanks its a perfect solution :- order by field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using ->order()   Add order( 'id' ) to your code this way:

```
 $first_array = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('form_fields')                                      
         ->where(array('not in', 'id', $sorted_array))
         ->andWhere('form_id=:form_id', array(':form_id'=>$form_id))
         ->order('id')
         ->queryAll();
```

otherwise if is not possibile build the query you need with query builder you can use

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from your_table")->queryAll();
```

and for binding param

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand(
        'select * from your_table  where yuor_field =:your_param')->
      bindValue('your_param',$yuor_value)->queryAll();
```

this returns all rows using a  specified SQL statement

```
$sql = "select * from form_fields 
       where id not in (3,1,6) 
       and form_id = " . $form_id .
       "order by field(id, 3,6,1);";

$first_array = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

Comment: i think order by field is the one for my problem

Comment: well i got the answer before you posted it courtsey @Sougata. But thanks for the answer and its explanation